# How to set active link in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react and I just want to know how set nav-pills active using react js i am using bootstrap with react js

I have tried setState for this

I am not getting result

Comment: Could you share some of your code with us?

Comment: can you please post some code , what you have tried yet, so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

1. set a class to your to your pills likeTablinks
2. make the function that  picks the tab with class name with your js dom fucntions,then perform dom related changes like adding active to your class
   3.now callthe above function onclick:

   ```
   makeclickactive = (evt)=>{
   // Declare all variables
   let tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");//getting the nav pills
   for (let i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
       tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   evt.currentTarget.className += "active";
   ```

   }

call the above function as is:

```
    onClick={this.makeclickactive}
```